# Numpy Group Reshaping / Indexing

Tags: python, numpy

The situation is I'd like to take the following Python / NumPy code:

```
# Procure some data:
z = np.zeros((32,32))

chunks = []
for i in range(0,32,step):
    for j in range(0,32,step):
        chunks.append( z[i:i+step,j:j+step] )
chunks = np.array(chunks)
chunks.shape # (256, 2, 2)
```

And vectorize it / remove the for loops. Is this possible? I don't mind much about ordering of the final array, e.g. 256,2,2 vs 2,2,256, as long as the spatial structure remains the same. That is, blocks of 2x2 from the original array.

Perhaps some magic using `::` in addition to regular indexing can do this? Any NumPy masters here?

Comment: it seems like a manual `reshape`. Why wasn't that an option?

Comment: e.g. `chunks = z.reshape((-1, step, step))`

Comment: @Marat that wouldn't give the desired output, being grouping four consecutive values into one 2x2 blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need `transpose`:

```
a = np.arange(1024).reshape(32,32)

a.reshape(16,2,16,2).transpose((0,2,1,3)).reshape(-1,2,2)
```

Output:

```
array([[[   0,    1],
        [  32,   33]],

       [[   2,    3],
        [  34,   35]],

       [[   4,    5],
        [  36,   37]],

       ...,

       [[ 986,  987],
        [1018, 1019]],

       [[ 988,  989],
        [1020, 1021]],

       [[ 990,  991],
        [1022, 1023]]])
```

Comment: A numpy master has emerged