# Split matrix in python into square matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Is there a quick and easy way to split a `MxN` matrix into matrices of size `AxA` (square matrices) starting greedily from the top left in python specifically? I had a 2d numpy array.

For example

```
1 2 3 4 
6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4
6 7 8 9
0 0 0 0
```

If I want to split into `2X2` the outcome should be a list like:

```
1 2 
6 7

3 4 
8 9

1 2 
6 7

3 4 
8 9
```

(Notice the `0 0 0 0` at the bottom gets left out)

Is there a "clean" way to write this? I can write it in brute force but it is not at all pretty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy Group Reshaping / Indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62843043/numpy-group-reshaping-indexing)

Answer (score 0):

You may do this in one line (using numpy) by:

```
test = np.arange(35).reshape(5,7)
M, N = test.shape
A = 2
print(test)
print('\n')

split_test = test[0:M-M%A, 0:N-N%A].reshape(M//A, A, -1, A).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(-1, A, A)

print(split_test)
```

Output of above code is:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9 10 11 12 13]
 [14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
 [21 22 23 24 25 26 27]
 [28 29 30 31 32 33 34]]


[[[ 0  1]
  [ 7  8]]

 [[ 2  3]
  [ 9 10]]

 [[ 4  5]
  [11 12]]

 [[14 15]
  [21 22]]

 [[16 17]
  [23 24]]

 [[18 19]
  [25 26]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using skimage:

```
a = np.r_[np.add.outer((1,6,1,6),range(4)),[[0,0,0,0]]]

from skimage.util import view_as_windows

sz = 2,2
view_as_windows(a,sz,sz)
# array([[[[1, 2],
#          [6, 7]],
#
#         [[3, 4],
#          [8, 9]]],
#
#
#        [[[1, 2],
#          [6, 7]],
#
#         [[3, 4],
#          [8, 9]]]])
```